# error al listar una API en angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, tabla-dinámica

Gente tengo un problema.
tengo una tabla con las siguientes columnas |nombre|estado|modificar|eliminar|habilitar|
el nombre lo listo de una api de spring boot y las demas columnas son iconos donde, si elimino a la persona el icono de estado cambia de verde a rojo simulando que esta eliminando pero sigue ahi. y habilitar lo cambia de rojo a verde.
El problema comienza aqui, al hacer un habilitar esta perfecto, pero el eliminar me da error en consola pero lo elimina. Ambos estan exactamente los mismo solo  que se cambia el estado de 0 a 1, y de 1 a 0.
Metodos del .ts

```
eliminar(){
    this.areaService.eliminarArea(this.codigo).subscribe(response =>{
      console.log("se esta eliminando: "+this.codigo+".");
      console.log("Se elimino correctamente");
      this.areaService.getListaFiltrada().subscribe(response =>{
        this.areaService.apiArea=response;
    });
    },
    error =>{
      console.log("error ELIMINACION");
    });
    this.modalReference.close();
    this._success.next(`LA PERSONA FUE ELIMINADA`);
  }

  ////////////////////HABILITAR
  habilitar(){
    this.areaService.recuperarArea(this.codigo).subscribe(response =>{
      console.log("se esta recuperando: "+this.codigo+".");
      console.log("Se recupero correctamente");
      this.areaService.getListaFiltrada().subscribe(response =>{
        this.areaService.apiArea=response;
      });
    },
    error =>{
      console.log("error RECUPERAR");
    });
    this.modalReference.close();
    this._success.next(`LA PERSONA FUE RECUPERADA`);
  }
```

olvide mencionar que despues de eliminar y habilitar llamo a getListaFiltrada que es mi servicio que me devuelve el todos los datos de spring, para que no este recargando la pagina cada que haga una modificacion de eliminar o habilitar.

**el habilitar se refresca la lista y da todo bien, pero el eliminar me devuleve en consola del navegador el ERROR ELIMINACION y no me refresca la lista**

pdta: si el getListaFiltrada lo pongo despues que cierra la llave del error =>{...} tampoco se refresca la lista.

**actualizacion**
mi servicio en angular

```
//eliminar area PUT
eliminarArea(coda: number): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.put(this.baseUrl+'/eliminarArea/'+ coda,coda);
}

//recupera area PUT
recuperarArea(coda: number): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.put(this.baseUrl+'/recuperarArea/'+ coda,coda);
}
```

en el backend
controlador

```
    // ELIMINA AREA
    @Transactional
    @PutMapping("/api/eliminarArea/{coda}")
    public String eliminaArea(@PathVariable int coda) {
        int area3 = areasrepo.eliminaArea(coda);
        return "ok";
    }

    // RECUPERA AREA
    @Transactional
    @PutMapping("api/recuperarArea/{coda}")
    public void habilitaArea(@PathVariable int coda) {
        int area4 = areasrepo.recuperaArea(coda);
    }
```

backend repository

```
    //ELIMINA AREA
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE areas SET estado = 0 WHERE coda = :coda", nativeQuery = true)
    int eliminaArea(@Param("coda") int xcoda);
    
    //RECUPERA AREA
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE areas SET estado = 1 WHERE coda = :coda", nativeQuery = true)
    int recuperaArea(@Param("coda") int xcoda);
```

quitando el error que le daba

```
    error =>{
      console.log("error RECUPERAR");
    }
------------------------------
error =>{
      console.log("error ELIMINAR");
    }
```

me lanza este error en consola del navegador

```
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: 'ok'}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/api/eliminarArea/7"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/eliminarArea/7"
[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase
```

este error me da al eliminar, aun y con el error me lo elimina pero tengo que recargar la pagina para ver los cambios, mientras que el recuperar se ejecuta bien y no me da error

Comment: A ver... te da error y lo único que nos muestras es un string que te inventas tú? Dime cómo quieres que sepa qué error te da si lo único que veo es el string que tú pones cuando hay un error??? Si quieres que te ayudemos (y que puedas debugar tu!) lo más importante que se debe hacer cuando ocurre un error es DEJAR CONSTANCIA DEL ERROR. No *ocultarlo* con un mensaje bonito. Los mensajes entendibles son para usuarios, a los desarrolladores se les debe enseñar el error "en bruto" para poder arreglarlo. Necesitamos saber exactamente qué error, y además ver el código de tu servicio y backend!

Comment: lo puse la parte que supongo donde me da el error, soy nuevo en el desarrollo y en esta pagina amigo, espero que me entiendan. y agradecería su ayuda

Comment: El mensaje de error _real_ te dice `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0`(...). Fijate en esa **o**. Ahora, te pregunto: en la línea `return "ok";` ¿es `ok` un JSON válido?

Comment: es solo una cadena que muestro, pero no me da error en habilitar y devuelvo lo mismo, ahora como deberia tener mi return?

Comment: regresa un objeto, o un texto formateado a json

Comment: listo, solucionado, gracias a todos.